# Getting Error during uploading Database to my server. SQL error #1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Error
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `crypto_files` (
  `fileID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fileTitle` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `fileName` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fileSize` double(15,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fileText` text,
  `priceUSD` double(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `priceCoin` double(17,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `priceLabel` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `purchases` mediumint(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `userFormat` enum('MANUAL','COOKIE','SESSION','IPADDRESS') NOT NULL,
  `expiryPeriod` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lang` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `defCoin` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `defShow` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `image` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `imageWidth` smallint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `priceShow` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `paymentCnt` smallint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `paymentTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `u[...]
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'TYPE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 45

Getting this error while uploading sql file. Please help me 
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

`TYPE=InnoDB` has changed to `ENGINE=InnoDB`.

Do not use `DOUBLE(m,n)` it leads to double rounding and has no benefits.  Switch to either `DOUBLE` or `DECIMAL(m,n)`.